# Dotnet core 2.0 Use Identity with JwtBearer Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, jwt, .net-core-2.0

In my Asp.Net core web api I was using Identity with Jwt bearer authentication. It was working smoothly without any fuss. Here is the code for that,

**ConfigureServices():**

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext, int>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**Configure():**

```
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = "localhost:4200",
                    ValidAudience = "localhost:4200",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SuperSecretKey_GetThisFromAppSettings")),
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                }
            });
```

And today I upgraded to .net core 2.0 and the entire technology stack. From the limited help available out there I have modified code like this..

**ConfigureServices()**

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();   



services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "localhost:4200";
                    options.Audience = "localhost:4200";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "localhost:4200",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SuperSecretKey_GetThisFromAppSettings"))
                };
            });
```

**Configure()**

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Now the authentication is not working. Looks like its internally configured to use Cookie Authentication.

Has anyone else come across this scenario? Any help on this is really appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly from the MS site

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

Identity adds cookies and sets the default authentication to the cookie scheme.
Try changing your

`services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`

to

```
services.AddAuthentication(o => {
  o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

Comment: Hey, it worked! and thanks lot. But I have one more question. Do you know how to stop default redirection to login page during an unauthorized access? Instead of redirection I need to sent the http status code to the client.

Comment: No problem, I assume there are better ways but because you are using Identity and CookieAuthentication as a 2nd auth scheme you can use the login path because it falls back onto it.
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/somecontr/somefunc";
}); and return whatever you need.
public IActionResult somefunc() return StatusCode(418)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question:

> Do you know how to stop default redirection to login page during an unauthorized access?

I found this blog post by [PioneerCode](https://pioneercode.com/post/authentication-in-a-asp-dot-net-core-api-part-1-identity-access-denied) for dotnet core 1 which may be helpful.

This is how I implemented it and it worked:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/api/login";
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
      OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
      {
        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
        {
          ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
          return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: This is cookie, not bearer